# Accessibility issue with popup and aria-live

Tags: javascript, html, accessibility

I have a error message on which I am using aria-live = polite.
It is announce the first time error is there.
The second time it again announce if I open a popup on that same page and error has occurred in that page.

```
<div aria-live="polite">
<error-message-component></error-message-component>
</div>
```

I am not able to find why it is happening as it has been already announce to the user and content behind the popup has aria-hidden="true"

Comment: Which screen reader are you using?  Is this consistent between different screen readers?

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that the error message (aria-live) is announced twice?  The first time is expected, but if you open a popup, it's announced a second time?

If you are **only** specifying `aria-live="polite"` and are **not** specifying [`aria-relevant`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-relevant), then that means the aria-live region should be announced anytime you change text (add, remove, or change text) within the <div> (or any of its child DOM elements), or if you **add** child DOM elements (but not **remove** child DOM elements).

So you should confirm that when you display the popup, that no child DOM nodes are added to your aria-live region and that no text within the aria-live region is changed.

Also check if the aria-live region is somehow referenced by your popup.  If something in your popup has an `aria-labelledby` or `aria-describedby` that points to the aria-live region, then the aria-live region will be announced as part of the popup.

Comment: I think it is happening due to aria-relevant as I am adding aria-hidden attribute at aria-live region. Can it be issue. Is there a way to resolve this ?

Comment: adding the `aria-hidden` attribute to the live region will not cause the live region to be read.  without actual code to look at, it's hard to guess what the problem is

Comment: I found the problem I guess. There was a tabindex inside of my <error-message-component>. The moment I removed tabindex it started working. But I am not able to figure out how it might have happened due to tabindex 0

Comment: Adding `tabindex="0"` will not automatically cause a live region to be announced.  It **will** allow the user to TAB to the live region, and at that point it'll be announced because it has the current keyboard focus.